# What is the functional form of $r = e^{\tan(\theta)}$?

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric, inverse-function

$r = e^{\tan(\theta)}$ generates a functional curve. How can this be converted to cartesian form? Or, is it transcendental?

What I've got so far:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vbc3muenfo
The parametric form of the curve is $ ( e^{\tan(t)}\cos(t), e^{\tan(t)}\sin(t)  )$. Both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are periodic with seemingly functional periods. Can a single-branched inverse resembling the inverse trigonometric functions be defined on some period?

UPDATE: Parametric form might not be necessary.

When converting polar equations to cartesian equations, $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\tan(\theta)=\frac yx$ by the definition of the tangent function and the pythagorean theorem. Therefore, by substitution:

$r = e^{\tan(θ)} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=e^\frac yx$

How can this be converted to a function of the form, $y=f(x)$?
Visual: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/plngic6rdq

Comment: hum, i don't think there a nice funtion in form of $y=f(x)$ for that case, at least not in term of elementary function.

Comment: What about a non-elementary function?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&x\tan\theta\\
&=&x\ln(r)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}x\ln\left(x^2+y^2\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

not sure if that right, but you have that (catersian and polar relations)
$$x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$$
so divide both to have
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta}=\tan\theta$$
and
$$x^2+y^2=(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2=r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r^2$$
so
$$r=e^{\tan\theta}\\
r^2=e^{2\tan\theta}\\
x^2+y^2=e^{\frac{2y}{x}}$$
or considering $r>0$ we can assume that $\sqrt{r^2}=r$ so
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=e^{\frac{y}{x}}$$